# View details in new Google maps after "search nearby"

Tags: google-maps

If I use the "search nearby" feature on the new Google Maps, I see a nice collection of results but I don't know how to find more details about each result.

If I click on the search result (in the screenshot, this is *La Bruschetta*), no additional information appears. If I hover over the result I get extremely limited info, but no website link etc. (as shown in screenshot).

I'm obviously missing something - how do I see additional data? In the old maps, this was quite easy - click the result.

**Note**: this only seems to affect the "Search nearby" feature. If I just search for the restaurant by name and click on it, the details appear under the search pane as expected.

[image: Example screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But if you click on the pin (or on the small red icon representing a restaurant), it will open the details under the search box. (I also tried it with *Ignite* and other results seen on the map and I got the same result—the details under the search box.)

[image]

Comment: I also observe those results when I simply search for the restaurant. However, try searching nearby and *then* start clicking on results. The behaviour is different.

Comment: Bizarre, it's now working. It almost feels like Google are making minor changes to Maps as I'm working with it this afternoon. Hmmm. Thanks for the response.

Comment: The new version is in “rollout process” currently, so it might have just been a temporary caching/deployment issue.